# Can't get the 'sails-generate-new-with-mast' generator to work in sails 0.10

Tags: node.js, sails.js

working with sails beta v0.10-rc8 installed globally. i'm using mac osx 10.9.

```
sudo npm install sails@beta -g
```

Then I installed the generator npm package both globally (just to give it a shot) and locally in the folder that will contain the project to be generated like:

```
~/projects& npm install sails-generate-new-with-mast
```

created the .sailsrc file in the folder containing the project

```
~/projects/.sailsrc
```

and in

```
~/.sailsrc
```

the file content is:

```
{
    generators: {
        modules: {
            new: 'sails-generate-new-with-mast'
        }
    }
}
```

when trying to use

```
~/projects$ sails generate new MyApp
```

the default generator is used.

What am I doing wrong? tried for a while but couldn't do it.

Thanks in advance!.

TR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are a really powerful new feature of Sails v0.10, but the system for utilizing custom ones is still a bit clunky.  You were on the right track, but you need to install the generator in your home directory (**~/node_modules/sails-generate-new-with-mast**) and add a **.sailsrc** file in your home directory with an absolute path to the generator:

```
{
    generators: {
        modules: {
            new: '/Users/myusername/node_modules/sails-generate-new-with-mast'
        }
    }
}
```

Then `sails new` will use that generator.

I must warn you that Mast is completely unsupported and, sadly, pretty much abandoned.