# How can the boilerplate for SailsJS model generation be changed

Tags: sails.js

I've tried changing the models.ejs file located in: `node_modules/sails/bin/boilerplates/templates`

Seems to ignore any change I make in there.

Comment: I ended up adding a template to my IDE to generate the models the way I want them.

Comment: This question pertained to sails v0.9. In sails v0.10 the boilerplate templates are located `sails\node_modules\sails-generate\node_modules\sails-generate-model\templates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing `sails generate model`, it's using the code in the globally installed Sails, so you'd have to change the template there.  On OS X Sails installs globally to **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails**, but it may vary by system.

This is one of the reasons that Sails v0.10 moved to using [separate generators](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-model) rather than baked-in templates!

Comment: There are no templates (at least not that I could find) under the global sails install directory tree. Documentation on overriding an existing generator is hard to come by.

Comment: For Sails v0.9, the templates are under **/bin/boilerplates/templates** in the Sails install directory.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767399/cant-get-the-sails-generate-new-with-mast-generator-to-work-in-sails-0-10) for an example of overriding a generator in Sails v0.10.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that question, I will take a look. As for my original question finding the templates wasn't an issue. I mentioned same location you did in the question. However, changing them had no effect. Perhaps you are saying that the changes should have worked and something else must be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible you have Sails v9 installed locally in your project, and v10 installed globally?  If your global Sails install is version 0.9.x, then the **bin/boilerplates/templates** directory should definitely exist in the global install, and changing those templates should change what happens when you do `sails generate model foo`.

Comment: Oops. Yep. I installed v10 after I posted the question but before I went looking in the global install location. Thanks.